# as3 - how to stop animation when both keys pressed?

Tags: actionscript-3

My player stops moving when two keys are pressed at the same time. But the animation still moves. For example, if I press up and down at the same time or right and left at the same time.

On key down event listener:

```
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
        {
            isRight = true
        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
        {
            isLeft = true
        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
        {
            isUp = true
        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.S)
        {
            isDown = true
        }
```

On key up event listener:

```
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
        {
            isRight = false
            gotoAndStop(1);
        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
        {
            isLeft = false
            gotoAndStop(1);
        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
        {
            isUp = false
            gotoAndStop(1);
        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.S)
        {
            isDown = false
            gotoAndStop(1);
        }
```

On enterframe:

```
if (isRight == true)
        {
            x += 5;
            play();
        }
        if (isLeft == true )
        {
            x -= 5;
            play();
        }
        if (isUp == true)
        {
            y -= 5;
            play();
        }
        if (isDown == true)
        {
            y += 5;
            play();
        }
```

Comment: Did we not solve something similar yesterday? Please make everything false before setting anything to true in your Key down listener. Looks like something remains true.

Comment: If I do that, that sorta messes up my movement. I decide to remain it like this.

Comment: Ok in that case, put some traces in your key up key down and see what all values remain true? And how does it mess up your code if you put everything to false?

Comment: It makes the movement less fluid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If players goes x -= 1 and x += 1 it basically moves x += 0 overall. We can easily check that and stop animation in needed:

```
var iP:Point = new Point(x,y);//try to avoid creating new objects on frame interval
if (isRight) x += 5;
if (isLeft) x -= 5;
if (isUp) y -= 5;
if (isDown) y += 5;
if(!Point.distance(iP,new Point(x,y)) goToAndStop(1);
else play();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any checks to see if more than 1 key is being pressed?

surely you should introduce something like a keycount into the enterframe:

```
var count:uint = 0;

if (isRight == true){
    count++
    x += 5;
}
if (isLeft == true ){
    count++;
    x -= 5;
}
if (isUp == true){
    count++;
    y -= 5;
}
if (isDown == true){
    count++
    y += 5;
}

if (count > 1) {
    isRight = isLeft = isUp = isDown = false;
    gotoAndStop(1);
} else {
    play();
}
```

Comment: Wait, but I tried this method, and then my player starts moving when both of keys are pressed.

Comment: I've tweaked it so that the play is conditional.

If the player still moves when both keys are pressed then you should definitely put trace statements into the  if/else to see what's being fired and when.

Also I'd remove the 'gotoAndStop(1)' from the up listener and let the enterframe handle all of the timeline logic.